# Smarty Breadcrumbs "Link" issues

Tags: php, smarty, breadcrumbs

I'm looking to create a navigation breadcrumb on my CMS Made Simple site. I'm looking to use smarty/php but I'm having problems making sure it's future-proof - i.e can handle multiple levels.

Here's the sample tree structure I am looking to get working:

```
-Root
-About us
--Test
---Level 3
-Services
-Contact Us
```

Here's my code (minus styling):

```
{assign var="uri" value=$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI|pathinfo}
{assign var="exploded" value="/"|explode:$uri["dirname"]}

<a href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}">Home</a>

{foreach from=$exploded item=element}
 {if $element != ""}

    ::<a href="http://{$smarty.server.HTTP_HOST}/

        {foreach from=$exploded item=element2}
             {if $element2 != ""}
                {$element2}/
             {/if}       
        {/foreach}

     ">{$element|replace:'-':' '}</a>

 {/if}{*close the if blank if*}
{/foreach}
::{$uri["filename"]|replace:'-':' '}
```

And here's my current output

```
<a href="http://www.libraryplustrust.org.uk">Home</a>
:: <a href="http://www.libraryplustrust.org.uk/about-us">about us</a>
:: <a href="http://www.libraryplustrust.org.uk/test">test</a>
:: level3
```

Problem is that the 2nd layer (test) is not being "added on" to the "about-us" parent file. Any ideas would be warmly received.

Comment: What exactly URL do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing it yourself, I would suggest using CMS Made Simple's builtin plugin for it:

```
{cms_breadcrumbs template="breadcrumbs" root="Root"}
```